# Escape single backslash in MySQL JSON INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, string, escaping, mysql-json

I'm trying to encode a regex in a JSON data field in a MySQL database.
The regex is as follows: `^\d*[13579]$` and should look the same, if I try to read it afterwards.
AFAIK, for single backslash escaping in SQL I need double backslashes.
However, when is replace the single backslash with two like this:
`^\\d*[13579]$`, I get an error stating:
`Invalid JSON text: "Invalid escape character in string."` and my IDE also shows it as an error. When I use another set of two backslashes, the error disappears, but I also get two backslashes in the final string.

Any idea, what the problem might be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The double-backslash is correct for JSON.

JSON has its own escape sequences, similar to the escape sequences in regular expressions. In JSON, `\b` means backspace, `\n` means newline, `\t` means tab, and so on. If you want to store a literal backslash character, use `\\`. Otherwise the backslash must be followed by one of the recognized escape sequences.

If you store a literal backslash character in a JSON value, it must be a double backslash. If you extract that JSON value and "unquote" it, it will be returned as a single backslash as you intended.

Demo:

```
mysql> create table t ( j json );

mysql> insert into t set j = '["^\\\\d*[13579]$"]';

mysql> select j from t;
+-------------------+
| j                 |
+-------------------+
| ["^\\d*[13579]$"] |
+-------------------+

mysql> select j->>'$[0]' from t;
+--------------+
| j->>'$[0]'   |
+--------------+
| ^\d*[13579]$ |
+--------------+
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. So the only way is to store double-double-backslashes and "unquote" them? Can I make the "unquoting" happen automatically, or do I have to specify it in every query?

Comment: You'd want to do the unquoting anyway when you fetch any string field from a JSON document, or else you get a string that includes literal double-quotes. Welcome to using JSON! In almost every case I see people using JSON in MySQL, they would have been better off using normal columns.

Comment: Alright, now I get what you mean! Unfortunately, this does not work in my case. In the DB, the JSON is still saved with two backslashes, which then are replaced by four backslashes by the db driver, which means I end up with two backslashes again.

Comment: I have not experienced this, and I don't know what db driver you're using.